# Django.contrib.auth.authenticate fail when I update the user.email field - Worked with previous credentials before email update

Tags: django-forms

I created a form where logged-in users can change their email address. After the new email is saved there seems to be no matching query for the email/password combination. I checked the database entry for the specific user instance and the email was changed as expected. Even when I used `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` to match email/password it couldn't match. What am I doing wrong? Below is the form and view I used:

> Forms.py

```
class UpdateEmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    new_email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['new_email', 'password']

    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        old_password = cleaned_data.get('password')

        if not check_password(old_password, self.instance.password):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Incorrect password. Please try again.')

        return cleaned_data
```

> Views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    context = {'form': form}

    if request.POST.get('user_login'):

        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Email and Password does not match.')
            return redirect('login')

    return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
```

Below is where I handle the new email form data
    @login_required
    def profile(request):
        ...
        elif request.POST.get('update_email'):
            data = Customer.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
            email_form = UpdateEmailForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

```
        if email_form.is_valid():
            email_form.save()
            email = request.POST.get('new_email')
            user = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
            user.email = email
            data.email = email
            data.save()
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been updated successfully')
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            return render(request, 'users/profile.html', {'data': data, 'email_form': email_form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating a new field named `confirm_password` rather than using the actual field `password`. The password is changed or not saved when I save the form using the actual password field

```
Class UpdateEmailForm(forms.Forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    confirm_password = models.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        fields = ['confirm_password', 'new_email']
```